# How to create an ease-in-out for image hover replacement in html?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is the image replacement code I am currently using in various parts of our website, to do a hover image replacement. My question is how to add an ease-in-out .5s to the existing code, or an alternative CSS code to our stylesheet for use throughout our website. I am looking to create a smoother transition between images. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<img src="https://gingerhippo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/GingerHippo-Search-Services-3-1.jpg" 
     onmouseover="this.src='https://gingerhippo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Ginger-Hippo-Search-Services-1-1.jpg'" 
     onmouseout="this.src='https://gingerhippo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/GingerHippo-Search-Services-3-1.jpg'"
>
```

On our home page, you will see 7 different image hover replacement images, all with no transition timing. I've managed to create background transitions for what looks like buttons on our blog and industry articles pages, but can't replicate the process for our main page imagery.

Thank you again in advance for your help. I've been stuck on this for a couple of months.

Comment: @A.Sakkeer You copy-pasted a link. This is against the guidlines of stack-overflow.

Comment: my apologies. I hadn't posted here. I will remove the link. It wasn't my intention to cheat the rules, rather give reference to the issue.

Comment: @A.Sakkeer So you have patented standard CSS code?  Read his question again and then read your answer. Does your answer solves his problem? and after that read my answer in the bottom of it I have mentioned the source, compare your source with it.

Comment: @GingerHippo Why are you using onmouseover and out when you can do the same using pure css? If you want to do this using javascript then call functions on mouse events like `onmouseover="this.changeImage()"` and `onmouseout="this.revertImage()"` after that you can change image and apply javascript animation using functions.

Comment: @Robert Williams If I change the example to CSS, it seems like it would cause less conflict. When I use the image replace examples below with the cross fade, there isn't an exact image replacement (10px bleed on bottom), I'm guessing due to the negative margins. Please keep in mind that I'm not a coder at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two images in an outer block element.

```
<section>
    <img class="bottom" src="img.png">
    <img class="animation" src="img-2.png">
</section>
```

The outer will be relative and the inner will be absolute.

```
section {
  position: relative;
}

section img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Create the animation and apply it to the top element.

```
.animation {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Now if you want to edit the animation effect make changes in `.animation`.

Source: https://www.taniarascia.com/crossfade-between-two-images-with-css-animations/

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this [Example](http://www.bosspro.com/demo/)

```js
var $this = $(this);
  var newSource = $this.data("alt-src");
  $this.data("alt-src", $this.attr("src"));
  $this.attr("src", newSource);
};

$(function() {
  $("img.demo-img").hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

```html
<img class="demo-img" data-alt-src="image-2.png" src="image-1.png" />
```